# Live streaming using wowza server with bluetooth mike

Tags: android, video-streaming, audio-streaming, live-streaming, wowza

I need to stream audio from external bluetooth device and video from camera to wowza server so that I can then access the live stream through a web app.

I've been able to successfully send other streams to Wowza using the GOCOder library, but as far as I can tell, this library only sends streams that come from the device's camera and mic.

Does anyone have a good suggesting for implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

In the GoCoder Android SDK, the setAudioSource method of WZAudioSource allows you to specify an audio input source other than the default. Here's the relevant API doc for this method:

public void setAudioSource(int audioSource)

Sets the actively configured input device for capturing audio.

Parameters:
audioSource - An identifier for the active audio source. Possible values are those listed at MediaRecorder.AudioSource. The default value is MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER. Note that setting this while audio is actively being captured will have no effect until a new capture session is started. Setting this to an invalid value will cause an error to occur at session begin.